# Using Exchange Powershell to do a selective ItemCount

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm aware that it's very easy to use Get-MailboxStatistics to sum ItemCount and sizes and so on, but can anyone tell me how to do this selectively?

So an example here would be that I want to use e-mail item properties (fields) to selectively count. Imagine a scenario where I'm saying "okay, what's the item count in this persons mailbox where the "Follow Up Flag" is set, or what's the count of mail items that have an "Importance" flag.

Essentially I suppose I'm trying to make the equivalent of a search folder, but server side script, so the fields that I could use within Outlook to create a search folder based on e-mail fields I'd like to be able to "count" as part of a cmdlet.

Does that make sense? Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the Exchange management cmdlets that reaches that far into the mailbox items.  I think your best bet is going to be the EWS Managed API.

I'd start here:

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/#!/2012/01/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html